# Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}$ is a simple extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

My problem is "Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}$ is a simple extension"

I met a similar problem "Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}$ is a simple extension" and I showed that it is equal to Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}$. I let $u=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ and deduce that $u-\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{3})$, then square it and prove $\sqrt{2} \in Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$. However, the same technique cannot be applied in the first problem since we have 3 square root.

I actually found a proof for the first problem, by letting $u=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ and calculating $u,u^2,..., u^5$ and prove $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\in Q(u)$. Though it's not so nice. Looking for a simpler answer

Comment: Maybee you should add how you proved $Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3]=Q[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$ to give us an idea of your current knowledge of the subject. There are many ways to solve this problem and the best way depends on your machinery at hand.

Comment: See also: [Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$ a simple extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29846)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set of field homomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$ to $ \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and call it $\operatorname{Hom}$.
For $k \in \{2,3,5\}$ and $f \in \operatorname{Hom}$, we can send $\sqrt{k}$ only to $\sqrt{k}$ or to $-\sqrt{k}$, as $f(\sqrt{k})$ must be a root of $x^2-k$. Combining these possibilities, we obtain $2^3=8$ different elments in $\operatorname{Hom}$. Consider the element $\alpha = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$.
Note that for two different elements $f,g \in \operatorname{Hom}$, we have $f(\alpha) \neq g(\alpha)$, for example $\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5 \neq \sqrt2+ \sqrt3-\sqrt5$. Now consider $P$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
For any $f \in \operatorname{Hom}$ $f(\alpha)$ is a root of $P$. Thus $P$ has at least $8$ distinct roots in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, thus $\deg(P) \geq 8$.
But $\deg(P)=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] \leq [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$, so $\deg(P) = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] = 1$, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$.

Comment: Perhaps my brain has finally crumbled, but can you remind me why we know that there are $8$ different embeddings? Why, for instance, negating $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ doesn't force us to negate $\sqrt{5}$ also?

Comment: @ancientmathematician One definition of separability is that the number of embeddings is equal to the degree of the extension. We have shown that there are at most these 8 possibilities, but as there must be exactly 8, as every extension in characteristic 0 is seperable and this extension has degree 8.

Comment: Thanks; as I remember it. But it does mean your proof is a lot deeper than it appears on the surface. I'd expect a student to justify "has degree 8" as well; that is the essence of the problem with these famous sums of square roots of primes problems.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Does $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ mean $\mathbb{A}$, the algebraic numbers? 2) Why is $f(\alpha)$ a root of $P$ for any $f\in\mathsf{Hom}$?